# Ninject - Automatically bind all class within an assembly which inherit from generic base one (which in turn implement a generic interface)

Tags: c#, generics, binding, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a set of classes which inherit from base class, which in turn implements a generic interface. Here's an example:

```
public ConcreteClassForA : BasePlatformClass<ContractA> {}
public ConcreteClassForB : BasePlatformClass<ContractB> {}
public ConcreteClassForC : BasePlatformClass<ContractC> {}
```

Base platform is defined as

```
public BasePlatformClass<T> : IPlatform<T> {}
```

Is there a way I can automatically bind all ConcreteClass**X** classes to these generic implementations without specifying one after another? E.g. this works:

```
kernel.Bind<ConcreteClassForA>().To<IPlatform<ContractA>>()
```

But we're about to have hundreds of classes like this and don't want to manage a large Ninject module. It'd be far better if I could somehow fetch all of these classes from within an assembly and bind them automatically.

I don't mind a bit of reflection if necessary but I feel like this is something that Ninject offers out of the box, just not sure how...

I've tried several suggestions I found here but didn't manage to get it working...

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use Reflection and iterate through all classes

Comment: Definitiley, this is my last resort - but I feel like there has to be a support for something like this within Ninject.Extensions.Conventions package

Comment: Well, technically speaking, all this classes and generic interfaces are different types so even if such an extension exists it has to do one of two things: analyze the code to pick up the pattern you use and find types automatically (something along the lines of  what R# and Roslyn can do) or let you set the rules of which types should be mapped to which interfaces and use reflection to go through all types and apply your rules. Using both of these techniques will most likely be as complicated as your 'last resort'.

Comment: Yeah, this is just from a maintenance standpoint - I hate using reflection because it takes me half an hour just to get a grasp on what the code does :) Anyway I'll try to get this working this way and we'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Steven this is not a duplicate as related thread solves the injection of classes which implement an interface. My scenario is that all the classes inherit from BaseClass<T> which in turns implement Interface<T>. PLease remove the "duplicate" tag and bump the topic accordingly (as it's in the bottom of the posts' list).

Comment: I still beliebe this to be a duplicate because the answer to your question is _identical_ to the answer given. Only the supplied argument to the `InheritedFrom` should in your case replaced with your base class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just try https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces());
        var result = kernel.Get<IPlatform<ContractA>>();
```

Comment: This is not working because the classes implement a BaseClass which in turn implements interfaces. I gather that injecting an implementation of concrete to BaseClass is working, but not injecting an implementation to interface (it's missing the BaseClass part). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mirza, have you tried it? When I run the provided code, result is of type `ConcreteClassForA` as expected, isn't it?